# Debug C++ DLL with VSCode instead of Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-code, dll

Im working on a project where i need to debug a C++ DLL/Lib. I have the DLL/PDB/H/Source files and i need a "Client" to invoque the DLL so i can debug some functions.

So far i have in Visual Studio a solution for a "DLL Client".  To have it working i had to add my "Aditional Include Directories" (the .h file), the dll path on "Linker" and do a xcopy of the dll/pdb in "Build Events".
This is working but i dont like the visual studio interface very much and want to try to code/debug with VSCode.

My client is very simple so far:

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include "mydll.h"
    
    int main()
    {
        char version[20];
        GetVersion(version);
        std::cout << "Version: " << version << '\n';
    }
```

My DLL is made with a makefile. Im having trouble on how to set up my launch.json (or what to setup) on VSCode to add the include directories and the pdb info so when i run my client the dll/pdb is linked to the client.

The launch.json is the default of vscode only with a name change

```json
{"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(gdb) DLL Client",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/dllclient.out",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

Any help? Thanks

Comment: You probably need to show your `launch.json` also are you using the Makefile tools extension: [https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/now-announcing-makefile-support-in-visual-studio-code/](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/now-announcing-makefile-support-in-visual-studio-code/)

Comment: @drescherjm ill check on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i dont know if its the best solution but is the one i could find. Probably there is some way to improove this with the C++ extension of vscode.

launch.json (for debug)

```
{"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(gdb) VCVarsall 32",
        "type": "cppvsdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\main.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "targetArchitecture": "x86",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "preLaunchTask": "C++: vcvarsall Main 32",
    },
]}
```

tasks.json (to build main and link the library)

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "process",
            "label": "C++: vcvarsall Main 32",
            "command": "cmd",
            "options": {"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"},
            "args": ["/C vcvarsall x86 && cl /Od /Zi /EHsc /Fd:vc140.pdb /Fo:main.obj ./main.cpp /I ${workspaceFolder}\\dev /link ${workspaceFolder}\\libs\\mylibrary.lib /OUT:main.exe /PDB:vc140.pdb"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```